# Getting exception in retrieving data using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm retrieving data from my database using hibernate but getting an error.

[image]

My code for retrieving data is:

[image]

Comment: Why can't you post your code here directly? Also, while adding the code here, provide the code for Register class and hibernate mapping xml file

Comment: I just can't . I don't have so much reputation.

Comment: @superman you can. But it should be posted as text, not as an image. It's impossible to copy and paste snippets of code from an image.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Actually, I have to pass the name of class i.e. mapped to required table. 
Query query= session.createQuery("from Register");
instead of 
Query query = session.createQuery("from bank_employee") ;